# Print repeated elements from list - prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new at prolog. I need to write a simple program that print all elements that repeat in list more than once ([1,2,f,3,f,2] will return [f,2]). Thanks for any help!

Comment: I understand you're new at Prolog, but you'll need to show what you've tried and ask a more specific question. If you don't know where to start, I'd recommend searching for an [online tutorial](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) or textbook to learn the basics. You might want to check out some examples here to get some ideas: [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). You can also check the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info) link after clicking the Prolog tag and find lots of resources.

Comment: Why `[f,2]`? Why not `[2,f]`?

Comment: If you sort the list, using the standard `sort/2` predicate, would you be closer to a solution?